# Apache Camel set privateKey SFTP

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jsch, camel-ftp

I am trying to connect to a sftp server in order to store some files. I want to connect via the SSH. 
My question is almost identical with: 
[Camel SFTP component - SSH private key URI works with privateKeyFile, doesn't work with privateKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495686/camel-sftp-component-ssh-private-key-uri-works-with-privatekeyfile-doesnt-wo)
and the following answer: [Apache Camel - How to set a private key in a dinamic sftp endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396184/apache-camel-how-to-set-a-private-key-in-a-dinamic-sftp-endpoint) 
But I still I didn't manage to connect.

My working route:

```
 from(mytopic)
  .to(sftp://username@my.host:22/folder/?privateKeyFile=path/to/privateRsa)
```

My NON working route:

```
  from(mytopic)
  .to(sftp://username@my.host:22/folder/?privateKey=byteArrayRsa)
```

I debugged the com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair class -> following method:

```
public static KeyPair load(JSch jsch, byte[] prvkey, byte[] pubkey) throws JSchException
```

And seems that instead of having the correct byte[] prvkey, I got its address. 
How can I send the correct byte array? I tried to create a bean as it is suggested in one of the links, but it didn't worked. (I am using camel 3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work, you cannot simply use a ByteArray reference in a route definition. It works when you use a Registry like `org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry` to store the key reference.

```
simpleRegistry.put("MySshKey", byteArrayRsa)
camelCtx.setRegistry(simpleRegistry)
```

Then you can use a reference in the route:

```
privateKey=#MySshKey
```

Maybe you could also use Spring Injection.

Comment: This is working, I didn't thought to try it like this. Instead I have created a class with a method that returned my byteArray, I have annotated that class with @Component and I reference it like this, but it didn't worked. Do you have any idea why? Shouldn't all the beans be automatically added in the registry? (I am using camel 3.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully connected SFTP server using apache camel's SFTP component using the ssh private key. My requirement was to download files from SFTP server. Similarly, It can be applied to use SFTP to upload file, Sample code is as follows :

```
public class MySFTPFileTransferRoute extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("sftp://my_host/?username=user_name&password=&preferredAuthentications=publickey&useUserKnownHostsFile=false&privateKeyFile=/Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa")
                .to("file:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/source/").
                log("Upload file ${file:name} is complete.");

}
}
```